# Operate on [operands] or [operand]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Tag [operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operand): 122 questions, no tag wiki. Most questions seem to have to do with operands; the occasional question seems to be about [operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operators) (and may need to be retagged)

Tag [operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operands): 91 questions, tag wiki: "Operands differ from parameters in that they are the real values used or altered by a function, while the parameters are the named, abstract inputs used to define the function."

These tags refer to the same concept. I would like to propose that one of them be made a synonym of the other.

Comment: I'd go for making [operand] a synonym of [operands], just because [operators] is plural :D

Comment: It seems that `operator` does exist, it's a synonym of `operator-keyword`

Answer (score 2):

> Operands differ from parameters in that they are the real values used or altered by a function, while the parameters are the named, abstract inputs used to define the function.

I'm not sure that description is even accurate. Operands are the objects acted upon by *operators* (or mathematical operations). *Arguments* are the values operated on by functions. It's splitting hairs, but I think it's worth being precise in the tag wiki, even if the terms are often used synonymously in casual conversation.

Oh, and I'd keep the plural tag, just to be consistent.